# mysql: wp database update

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a following js and php:

**JS:**

```
var names = jQuery('#name').val();
data : {'action':'AJAX' , name:names },
```

The `#name` values are `"mike,sean,steve"`

**PHP:**

```
global $wpdb;
$names      = $_POST['name'];   
$table      = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_name';    
$RSS_UPDATE = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT update_number FROM $table WHERE id_name IN ($names)"); 

//update_number are int (example: 0,3,1,2)

$name  = explode(',', $names);
if ( $RSS_UPDATE ){
    foreach ( $RSS_UPDATE as $RSS_SINGLE ){         
        $RSS_ROW_NEW  = $RSS_SINGLE + 1;            
        $wpdb->update($table, array('update_number' => $RSS_ROW_NEW),array( 'id_name' => $name));               
    }   
}
```

So, few things:

**what I am trying to achieve:**

With the input values, get corresponding `update_number`. Then increase each value by "1" and update the same column with the new value.

**Errors**

1. `Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' for query SELECT update_number FROM wp_my_name WHERE id_name IN (Array)`
2. Just in general, something is not right...

Can someone help me out?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Does this look right?

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {    
    $names      = $_POST['name'];   //array
    $table      = $wpdb->prefix . 'rh_subs';
    $query      = "SELECT update_number FROM $table WHERE id_name = %s";    
    $RSS_UPDATE = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query, $names));
    if(!empty($RSS_UPDATE)) {
        foreach($RSS_UPDATE as $RSS_SINGLE) { // for each row
            $RSS_ROW_NEW  = $RSS_SINGLE->update_number + 1;
            $wpdb->update($table, array('update_number' => $RSS_ROW_NEW),array('id_name' => $RSS_SINGLE->id_name));
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what I've said in the comments in your earlier post, since you're taking multiple inputs, you'll need to use the `WHERE IN` clause.

The simple example would be like this:

```
$_POST['name']; // these are comma delimited string of names
// "mike,sean,steve"
```

So in essence, you'll need to construct them inside a `WHERE IN` clause like this:

```
WHERE id_name IN ('mike', 'sean', 'steve')
```

The unsafe and dirtiest way would be to just explode - put quotations on the strings - implode it back together with comma again:

```
$names = array_map(function($e){
    return "'$e'";
}, explode(',', $test));
$names = implode(',', $names);
// 'mike','sean','steve' // SATISFIES WHERE IN CLAUSE
// BUT UNSAFE!
```

So in order to do this safely, use the wpdb prepared statements. (This could get you started).

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $names = explode(',', $_POST['name']); // explode the comma delimited string into an array
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_name';  
    $stringPlaceholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($names), '%s')); // create placeholders for the query statement, this will generate
    $statement = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT update_number, id_name FROM $table WHERE id_name IN ($stringPlaceholders)", $names); // create the statement using those placeholders
    $RSS_UPDATE = $wpdb->get_results($statement); // execute

    // fetch resuls
    if(!empty($RSS_UPDATE)) {
        foreach($RSS_UPDATE as $RSS_SINGLE) { // for each row
            $RSS_ROW_NEW  = $RSS_SINGLE->update_number + 1;
            $wpdb->update($table, array('update_number' => $RSS_ROW_NEW),array('id_name' => $RSS_SINGLE->id_name));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Of course you can get creative yourself. I think you could combine the `UPDATE` and `WHERE IN` clause so that you'll just execute all of this once.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you meant before. Thank you! =)

Comment: @steveKim sure no prob glad this helped

Comment: I am getting following errors: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string` , `array_fill(): Number of elements must be positive`, `implode(): Invalid arguments passed` , `:Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(),` . lol Although I understand the logic behind. I am going to see if I can fix it.

Comment: @steveKim it comes down to that `$_POST['name']`, if thats an array of string already, then no need to `explode`, if it comes to you as a simple string with commas, then you'll need to explode it

Comment: I see. I will make some changes then. Thank you.

Comment: @steveKim made some edit on that prepare line, to be quite honest haven't used any wordpress in a long time, easy to follow the codex, it has examples too

Comment: I added "Edited" portion above. Could you take a look at it? Thank you.

Comment: @steveKim no, the part wherein the `$query` is wrong, instead of having `WHERE id_name = %s`, you should produce something like this `WHERE id_name IN(%s, %,s %s)` of course the number of `$s` will depend on how many elements are in there inside `$names (the array)` here's an example https://3v4l.org/XaH73

Comment: I changed to your suggestions and the only error i am getting is `Undefined property: stdClass::$id_name` on `$wpdb->update` section. Getting closer :P

Comment: @steveKim the error appeared you removed the select column `id_name` inside your query `SELECT update_number FROM $table` missing `id_name`. I already added that `id_name` in my answer

Comment: i see my error.  ! Thank you! =) Got it working.! =)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, It seems that $_POST['name'] returns an array.

You can view what exactly you are getting in $_POST['name'] by:

```
var_dump($_POST['name'], true);
```

Also For the id_name, if they are like these "mike,sean,steve" then you should do this for adding quotes for strings and the escaping issue so that they can be like this "'mike','sean','steve'" as you are using a `WHERE IN` clause:

```
$names = $_POST['name'];
if(!is_array($names)) $names = explode(",",$names);

$new_names = array();
foreach($names as $name){
    $name = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($name) : $name;
    $new_names[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
}
$names = implode(",", $new_names);
```

Comment: Please up vote and accept the answer if this helps so that I can open more privileges and help others.. If you have anything else just comment here, and I'll update my answer..

Comment: I added "Edited" portion above. Could you take a look at it? Thank you.

Comment: You can't do so, you should stick to IN clause as you are getting an array or a string that contains a number of names.

I can see the best solution is the `$new_names` data string refining I provided, it is only a few of lines and it insures that if the $names is a string or an array of many or of one, they both work. I had updated my code to accept all cases for your case.

Comment: So, could you update your answer to accommodate the array value? Also, at this point the only error I am getting is `"Undefined property: stdClass::$id_name"` on `$wpdb->update` section from my edited version.

Comment: I see. I will give it a try =)